# How to add Tailwind CSS in SvelteKit official demo application?

Tags: javascript, tailwind-css, svelte, sveltekit

I have created sample application by following steps given at https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/creating-a-project

```bash
npm create svelte@latest my-app
```

So the project structure is

```
alok@alok-HP-Pavilion-Laptop-14-dv0xxx:~/exp/my-app$ tree -L 3 --gitignore
.
├── jsconfig.json
├── package.json
├── package-lock.json
├── playwright.config.js
├── README.md
├── src
│   ├── app.d.ts
│   ├── app.html
│   ├── lib
│   │   └── images
│   └── routes
│       ├── about
│       ├── Counter.svelte
│       ├── Header.svelte
│       ├── +layout.svelte
│       ├── +page.js
│       ├── +page.svelte
│       ├── styles.css
│       └── sverdle
├── static
│   ├── favicon.png
│   └── robots.txt
├── svelte.config.js
├── tests
│   └── test.js
└── vite.config.js
```

This project already have `src/routes/styles.css` file and `import './styles.css';` inside  `src/routes/+layout.svelte` file.

Now I want to add Tailwind CSS by following https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/sveltekit

In this page they are asking to create `./src/app.css` and import it in `src/routes/+layout.svelte`

What I have to do with my existing `src/routes/styles.css` file?

What is right way to add Tailwind CSS in official demo app?

Answer (score 0):

The "right" way to start with TailwindCSS and the official SvelteKit demo is to follow the steps described in the tailwind documentation you linked and skipping the `step 6` as a CSS file is **already** generated and included in the layout.

Then on `step 5`, just add the TailwindCSS directives in the existing `style.css` file, below the font import.

```css
@import '@fontsource/fira-mono';
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

:root { ... }
...
```

That's it.

Feel free to ask more details by editing your question.